# Send message to specific subscription instead of topic in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Is it possible to send a message to a specific subscription instead of a topic in Azure Service Bus? I would like to send a message only to one subscription of a topic (which means all subscriptions will receive the message). It is somehow possible in the Azure portal (see screenshot), and I was wondering if it's possible with the REST API (or C# skd).

[option to send to a subscription in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgPkb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are **never** sent to a subscription. You always publish/send to a topic and subscriptions receive the messages that satisfy the criteria specified for **each** subscription via subscription rules. If you need a specific message type/payload to be received by only a single subscription, you need to specify the rules on that subscription to be the only subscription to evaluate the rules to true.

Alternatively, use a queue. A queue is good for a scenario when you know the receiver.

Comment: I do know that you “normally” never sent a message to a subscription. But in my case I want to re-send messages only to a subscription and because somehow you can send messages to a subscription in the Azure Portal, I though this should than also be possible in code.

Comment: The portal is using a misleading language. You'll end up sending a message to a topic, not a subscription.

Comment: what do you mean by "misleading language"?

Comment: "because somehow you can send messages to a subscription in the Azure Portal" - could you do that? I highly doubt that. Therefore the "send back to subscription" is misleading language. Messages cannot be sent/posted/published to a subscription. Queue or topic only.

Comment: If you look at the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgPkb.png) to the screenshot, you can definitely select one of the subscriptions, and then only that subscription is receiving the message.

Comment: Have you actually *tried* that? Were you able to send a message directly to a selected subscription rather that a topic? I doubt that as subscriptions **cannot** be targetted when sending messages.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's sending the messages to both queues. I didn't noticed that, sorry.

Comment: No worries. It was reported to Microsoft that the description in the portal is confusing and misleading but the change wasn't applied yet.